# Array Reduce functionality that is happening in the following code

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Hi I am looking into Angular 2.0 source code examples in https://angular.io/

I came across this following code. The function "remaining" essentially gets the number of elements in todos array where done is false. It is working fine, I just want to understand what's happening in reduce function. I have basic idea of how reduce function works, but could not understand the syntax here, particularly `count+ +!todo.done` . I am new to typescript.

```
export class TodoApp{
todos: Todo[] =[
    {text:"learn angular",done:true},
    {text:"build angular app",done:false}
];

get remaining(){
    return this.todos.reduce((count:number,todo:Todo) => count+ +!todo.done, 0);
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand how reduce method works, then you know that the part in callback is supposed to return sum of two values, namely, increment - if task is `undone` (add `1`) or add nothing (zero) if task is done, `done` equal to true.

This is exactly what this line does

```
count + +!todo.done
```

The part `+!todo.done` is just a confusing type casting and could be rewritten as

```
count + Number(!Boolean(task.done))
```

And now it should be clear because *toNumber* conversion of boolean values follows simple rule ([ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber)): 1 for true, 0 for false.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand it better.